# Measuring text width with font as org.faceless.pdf.PDFFont instance

Tags: java, pdf, text, width

I have text with font in org.faceless.pdf.PDFFont. How can I get width of it in px?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how to get the width in points (pixels don't really apply in PDF) then you can create a PDFStyle with that font and call PDFStyle.getTextLength() or PDFStyle.getTextWidths().

In general, if you have support questions for the BFO PDF Library please drop us an email at support at bfo.co.uk - that's what we're there for. All our contact details are at http://bfo.co.uk/contact.jsp.

Cheers... Mike @ BFO